# Problem with Await in File Handle Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I created an Webform application which allow user to upload file which using AJAX and FileHandle.ashx in Asp.Net
I'm trying to make it run asynchronous but it doesn't work as well.
The code below return "StartSavedEnd" which mean await doesn't work since my file take 10second to upload. Any advice? Many thanks

```
    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Start");

    await SaveFile(context);

    context.Response.Write("End");
    }
async Task SaveFile(HttpContext context)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            foreach (string key in files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                fileName = context.Server.MapPath(fileName);
                file.SaveAs(@"C:\TestZip.zip");
                context.Response.Write("Saved");

            }
        }
    });
    await task;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Webforms with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385376/asp-net-webforms-with-async-await)

Comment: @GSerg I've take a look at that thread but ConfigureAwait(false) doesn't work for me. No answer has been accepted as answer btw

Comment: Try replacing await SaveFile(context) by SaveFile(context).GetAwaiter().GetResult(). GetAwaiter/GetResult don't create a deadlock in legacy ASP.net. (unlike ASP.net Core)

Comment: @GuyatMercator It showing compile error "cannot wait for void" when i added .GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: Why don't you run this code simply synchronously? TaskRun will create another thread but you want to wait for the end of its execution. So sync execution seems to suit. Background tasks in webforms are not trivial. Have a look at this : http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make it run asynchronous but it doesn't work as well. The code below return "StartSavedEnd" which mean await doesn't work since my file take 10second to upload.

`await` doesn't make file uploads run faster, and [`await` doesn't return early from HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet).

In order to make your system seem more responsive, you'll need to do the upload in the background *on the client side*, e.g., using a technology like AJAX.